# retornar objeto retornado do banco para o front-end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Não estou entendendo o por que desses retornos

No servidor node.js:

```
//Insert user
router.post('/', async function(request, response) {
    let object = {
        name: request.body.userName, 
        password: request.body.userPassword
    }

    let insert = await serviceUser.insert(object);
    console.log(insert); //Aqui mostra todos os dados (id inserido, número de inserts, etc)
    response.send(insert);
});
```

No cliente em angular.js:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/user',
    data: {userName: 'teste', userPassword: '123abc'},
    mode: 'no-cors'
})
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.dataResponse = response;
    console.log(response); //Aqui aparece o header, status, ... e o atributo data (que contém o retorno do servivor) apenas com: { n: 1, ok: 1 }
})
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Por que isso? Gostaria que o retorno do servidor tivessem outros dados, como faço isso?

Observação: `data: { n: 1, ok: 1 }`, no front-end, é equivalente a `result: { n: 1, ok: 1 }`, no back-end, ou seja, esse atributo está no back mas só ele é retornado e não objeto pai inteiro. Não estou fazendo nenhum filtro para retornar só o `result`

Comment: Mas a questão tem a ver com a chave no retorno não ser a mesma ? `data` em contraste com `result` ? Ou os dados que obtem do lado do cliente não são os mesmos ?

Comment: @Isac exatamente, no servidor eu tenho o objeto completo e no cliente só tenho um atributo do objeto